# what are grafana "series name column" for?

Tags: grafana

What am I supposed to put in `<Series name column>`?

I'm trying to do a Pie chart dashboard and I don't know where can I see information for that.

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_column>) as time_sec,
  <value column> as value,
  <series name column> as metric
FROM <table name>
WHERE $__timeFilter(time_column)
ORDER BY <time_column> ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you have a table which contains columns 'server_name', 'cpu_load', 'reported_time'. So you can query this using

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(reported_time) as time_sec,
  cpu_load as value,
  server_name as metric
FROM cpu_measurements
WHERE $__timeFilter(reported_time)
ORDER BY time_sec ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand, metric is like the numer of lines in graphic or the type of something, so it can be TypeOfBug or something like that :)

Comment: should work. But there is one slight moment i want to mention. Grafana is just display/alerting system. It can only show data but can't make transformation - it totally relies on database functions. For example using graphite as time series database you can easily see pizza rate per second or standard deviation in comparison to previous periods to understand is it normal situation for Monday morning that you sell only 1 pizza or not. Perhaps such result can be achieved with custom functions for mysql.